# Combine multiple projections with conditions in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
 Orders.aggregate([{$match: { shippingType: "standardShipping" }},
                   { $project: { standardShippingCount: { $size: "$products" } } },
                  ])

   Orders.aggregate([{$match: { shippingType: "expressShipping" } },
                { $project: { expressShippingCount: { $size: "$products" } } },
                ])
```

I need help to find out if it's possible to write these 2 queries in 1.  Any help is appericated.

Comment: you can merge the `$match`  by `$or` operator but the problem is the dynamic fields name in project , i found this URL : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947 , actualy it is a bit costly so i advise to process it programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the number of total `products` ordered with each  `shippingType` from the whole collection, then you can use this aggregate query

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$products"
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$shippingType",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
]
```

It will give you a response in this format

```
[
  {
    "_id": "expressShipping",
    "count": 14
  },
  {
    "_id": "standardShipping",
    "count": 6
  }
]
```

Now to convert it into a format that suits your use-case

```
queryResponse.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[`${curr._id}Count`] = curr.count;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Finally, you'll have this

```
{
  expressShippingCount: 14,
  standardShippingCount: 6
}
```

Comment: You cant use $count in group operator, however I found $sum to be working in the same query. Thank you